# i am not able to run a programme with GPU acceleration in Cygwin, does cygwin allow GPU?

Tags: cygwin, gpu

i have installed Cygwin in my windows 10 to run a software called GROMACS. This software needs GPU acceleration for faster results. But currently the programme is not utilizing the GPU. Does cygwin blocks GPU? or do i need to install other programmes first before i run GROMACS.

Comment: Is GROMACS working without cygwin ? How you installed it ?

Comment: Do you have CUDA installed?

Comment: Yes sir my device manager shows nvidia quadro P4000

Comment: GROMACS is working in cygwin sir. i installed it using a online document given in GROMACS website.